# How can I Inheriting generic classes by Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Java, we can use this temp.

```
public class FatherClass<T1>{}
public class SonClass<T1,T2,T3> extents FatherClass<T1>{}
public class SubSonClass extents FatherClass<String, Integer, Character >{}
```

The build is ok.

But in Objective-C, always error when building.

```
@interface FatherClass <T1> : NSObject
@end

@interface SonClass <T1,T2,T3> : FatherClass<T1>
@end

@interface SubSonClass : SonClass <NSString*, NSNumber*, NSString* >
@end
```

Who knows about Objective-C of the generic specification document.

Comment: Yeah I think the generics in Objective-C are *light weight* and are used for more of a glorified casting system.  I couldn't find much about them on the Apple Developer site.

Comment: Thanks for your commit.
I find generics is very had for refactor the Class. If we add one key, you will update the class's subclasses and add the new key and define. if add a wrong word, Xcode can't help you, cuz Xcode is sick(The error you can't understand).


I was given update refactor current code. and use another way.